# Expand one MudNavGroup at a time in MudNavMenu

Tags: mudblazor

Is there a way I can expand one MudNavGroup at a time in MudNavMenu. In essence, when one MudNavGroup is being expanded, any MudNavGroup that was expanded should be collapsed.

I was hoping to find a property that I can set, but there seems to be none.

Note: MudNavGroup and MudNavLink and dynamically generated.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this could work:

##### NavMenu.razor

```cs
<MudNavMenu>
  @foreach (var item in this.MenuItems)
  {
    if (item.SubItems == null)
    {
      <MudNavLink Href="@item.Link.Url">@item.Link.Name</MudNavLink>
    }
    else
    {
      <MudNavGroup
        @ref="@this.subMenuItems[item.Link.Name]"
        Title="@item.Link.Name"
        ExpandedChanged="@(e => this.ToggleExpanded(e, item.Link.Name))">

        @foreach (var subItem in item.SubItems)
        {
          <MudNavLink Href="@subItem.Url">@subItem.Name</MudNavLink>
        }
      </MudNavGroup>
    }
  }
</MudNavMenu>

@code{
  private Dictionary<string, MudNavGroup> subMenuItems = new();

  [Parameter]
  public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; } = new();

  public record MenuItem(Link Link, List<Link>? SubItems = null);

  public record Link(string Name, string Url = "");

  private void ToggleExpanded(bool expanded, string itemName)
  {
    if (expanded)
    {
      foreach (var entry in this.subMenuItems.Where(entry => entry.Key != itemName))
      {
        entry.Value.Expanded = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And using it would then look like this:

```cs
<NavMenu 
  MenuItems="@(new List<NavMenu.MenuItem>
  {
    new(new NavMenu.Link("Home", "/")),
    new(new NavMenu.Link("Food"), new List<NavMenu.Link> { new("Food 1", "food/1"), new("Food 2", "food/2") }),
    new(new NavMenu.Link("Drinks"), new List<NavMenu.Link> { new("Drink 1", "drink/1"), new("Drink 2", "drink/2") })
  })"/>
```

[image]

And if you now expand the Drinks menu, the Food menu will collapse.